# MQL5 Time condition, trade once per hours

Tags: mql5, mql, metatrader5

does someone know a condition to trade only once per hour in mql5, i'm a begginer and having trouble to find something that i can undestand.
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

The best way is to simply have a time variable which you reset once per hour.

```
datetime TimeBar;

void OnTick()
{
   if(TimeBar==iTime(_Symbol,PERIOD_H1,0)) return;

   //Code to open a trade goes here

   TimeBar=iTime(_Symbol,PERIOD_H1,0);
return;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

As @PaulB said you can use iTime , but you can use **OnTimerEvent** too.